# Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics when using let

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this will be marked as duplicate, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.
If I have this code:

```
function createTableBody(table) {
    const rows = table.rows;

    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const cells = row.cells;

        console.log(row);

        for (let n = 1; n < cells.length; n++) {
            const cell = cells[n];
            const td = $(`#row-${i}-col-${n}`);

            console.log(cell);

            if (!cell.text) {
                td.html('N/A').removeClass('btn-cell').addClass('text-center');
            } else {
                const button = td.find('button')[0];

                $(button).html(cell.text);
                $(button).click(selectAppointment);
            }
        }
    }
}

function selectAppointment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e);
}
```

Everything works fine, but what I need to do is change the `click` event to this:

```
$(button).click(function(e) {
    selectAppointment(e, cell.attributes);
});
```

So the entire function will look like this:

```
function createTableBody(table) {
    const rows = table.rows;

    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const cells = row.cells;

        console.log(row);

        for (let n = 1; n < cells.length; n++) {
            const cell = cells[n];
            const td = $(`#row-${i}-col-${n}`);

            console.log(cell);

            if (!cell.text) {
                td.html('N/A').removeClass('btn-cell').addClass('text-center');
            } else {
                const button = td.find('button')[0];

                $(button).html(cell.text);
                $(button).click(function(e) {
                    selectAppointment(e, cell.attributes);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

function selectAppointment(e, attributes) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e);

    // Do something with the attributes
}
```

But when I try to save that I get the error:

> Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics.

Comment: You are skipping index 0 of the rows and columns, is that deliberate? Are `rows` and `cells` arrays?

Comment: Yes and Yes :) the first "cell" is empty and the first "row" is the header (which I handle with another function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `cells` and `.rows` are arrays, use `forEach` instead, and add one to the index:

```
function createTableBody(table) {
    const rows = table.rows;
    rows.slice(1).forEach(({ cells }, i) => {
        cells.slice(1).forEach((cell, n) => {
            const td = $(`#row-${i + 1}-col-${n + 1}`);
            if (!cell.text) {
                td.html('N/A').removeClass('btn-cell').addClass('text-center');
            } else {
                const button = td.find('button')[0];
                $(button).html(cell.text);
                $(button).click(function(e) {
                    selectAppointment(e, cell.attributes);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This way, you're using functions, rather than loops, which are not only generally easier to use, but also make the linter happy.

(if they're not arrays, you can easily convert them into one with `[...rows]`)